# Remove Class from ID if another link is clicked, vise versa

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working to find a solution for a jQuery problem.
I have a parent container with 2 divs and a link in each. If a link is clicked in one of the divs, a class is added to the parent container (to change the background). If the other link is clicked, I wanted to check if a class has already been added from the other link's click and be removed.

What's going on: When I click the first link, the class `inside-office` is added. Then I click the second link and it will add that without removing the first link.

Here's the code I have so far with no success:

```
$("a.in-office").click(function() {
    if($('#fullwrap').hasClass('outside-office')) {
    $(this).removeClass('outside-office');
    }
    $('#top_barwrap').parent().addClass('inside-office');
    $('.blockcase').fadeIn();
    $('.lead-title, .subtitle').fadeOut();
    $('#top_barwrap').animate( { height:'150px' }, { queue:false, duration: 500 });
});

$("a.out-office").click(function() {
    if($('#fullwrap').hasClass('inside-office')) {
    $(this).removeClass('inside-office');
    }
    $('#top_barwrap').parent().addClass('outside-office');
    $('.blockcase').fadeIn();
    $('.lead-title, .subtitle').fadeOut();
    $('#top_barwrap').animate( { height:'150px' }, { queue:false, duration: 500 });
});
```

Comment: `$('#top_barwrap').parent().addClass('inside-office');` You're using same classes for different elements? A HTML sample would be really valuable here.

Comment: Is `#fullwrap` the parent of `#top_barwrap`? If not where is `#fullwrap` class being set?

Answer (score 1):

Change the $(this) to $('#fullwrap') as you are checking the class on element with id "fullwrap".

Comment: Haha, you're awesome! I questioned that for a second before reading your post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need.
Explanation: Your $(this) is never referring to $('#fullwrap') which it should. Your $(this) is actually referring to either $('a.in-office') or $('a.out-office').

CORRECT CODE:

```
$("a.in-office").click(function() {
    var $this = $('#fullwrap');
    if($this.hasClass('outside-office')) {
        $this.removeClass('outside-office');
    }
    $('#top_barwrap').parent().addClass('inside-office');
    $('.blockcase').fadeIn();
    $('.lead-title, .subtitle').fadeOut();
    $('#top_barwrap').animate( { height:'150px' }, { queue:false, duration: 500 });
});

$("a.out-office").click(function() {
    var $this = $('#fullwrap');
    if($this.hasClass('inside-office')) {
        $this.removeClass('inside-office');
    }
    $('#top_barwrap').parent().addClass('outside-office');
    $('.blockcase').fadeIn();
    $('.lead-title, .subtitle').fadeOut();
    $('#top_barwrap').animate( { height:'150px' }, { queue:false, duration: 500 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `toggleClass`. It will remove the class if it exists, else add it.

```
$(this).toggleClass('outside-office');
```

If one of the class is already present, you can switch between the two classes using

```
 $(this).toggleClass('outside-office inside-office');
```